# View typer range information in V8

Tags: v8

I have been experimenting with V8 in the latest git revision, version `7.7.0 (canidate)` and `turbolizer`. However, if I try to get range information from the typer by running my source with `--trace-turbo` and then opening the result with `turbolizer`, it simply does not show anything, as opposed to the ranges shown in [this article](https://doar-e.github.io/blog/2019/05/09/circumventing-chromes-hardening-of-typer-bugs/).

My source:

```
var f = (o) => {
  let x = o.x;
  x += 0x4141;
  x += 0x2342;
  x += 0x1337;
  return x;
};

o = {x: 1234.5};
f(o);
f(o);
for(i=0;i<100000;i++) {
  f(o);
}
```

Result from turbolizer: [image]

Is there a way to get the range information back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last button in the toolbar row, with the `T` icon, means "toggle types". Try that ;-)

Comment: Ouch. Thank you. :)